# Object of class app\models\Users could not be converted to string in yii

Tags: php, string, yii

I created a two models: 
Login.php and Users.php

Where the Users.php I will get the data from the Users table.

Then, I have created a LoginController.php which is my controller

Then I ran my app I had received this error:
Object of class app\models\Users could not be converted to string

These are my codes:

Login.php:

```
    <code>`<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "users".
 *
 * @property string $user_id
 * @property string $first_name
 * @property string $last_name
 * @property string $position
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $dept_id
 */
class Login extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $post;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public static function getUsers()
    {
        $post = Users::find()
    ->where(['user_id' => 1])
    ->one();

    return $post;

    }
}`</code>
```

**Users.php**
    `` `

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "users".
 *
 * @property string $user_id
 * @property string $first_name
 * @property string $last_name
 * @property string $position
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $dept_id
 */
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'position', 'username', 'password', 'dept_id'], 'required'],
            [['user_id', 'dept_id'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['first_name', 'last_name'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['position', 'username', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => 'User ID',
            'first_name' => 'First Name',
            'last_name' => 'Last Name',
            'position' => 'Position',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'dept_id' => 'Dept ID',
        ];
    }
}
`</code>


LoginController.php
    <?php
    namespace app\controllers;
    use app\models\Login;
    class LoginController extends \yii\web\Controller
    {
        public function actionIndex()
        {
            // $this->layout = 'loginLayout';
            // $this->render('index');
            $details = new Login();
            $model = $details->getUsers();
            $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model)); 
        }
    } ``

I am new in YII I just started studying these

any answers will help thanks

Comment: When posting an issue, we need to see the file and line that are throwing this error in your case the `view` file. See [mcve] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In `Login` class You declared a static function `getUsers()`, then You try to use it as non-static in LoginController.php:11

```
$model = $details->getUsers();
```

Should be:

```
$model = Login::getUsers();
```

And it's only answer we can provide here - not contain a solution to Your problem - please attach view code so we will have a full preview.